# Issue running stored procedure from .net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this `stored procedure` :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTransactionFeeType_Pager]
      @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@ProgramName VARCHAR = ''
      ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY ID ASC
      )AS RowNumber
    ,FeeType,TransactionNumber,Amount,TransactionDate,ResponseDescription,PaidUsing

      INTO #Results
      FROM TransactionLog where FeeType=@ProgramName

      SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
      FROM #Results

      SELECT * FROM #Results
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

      DROP TABLE #Results
END
```

Basically it returns pagination......

Now the above runs fine when running from sql server and passing parameters as;

```
1    ,    10   ,     Deposit
```

However using the code below:

```
  string query = "[GetTransactionFeeType_Pager]";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", pageIndex);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", PageSize);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgramName", programID.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction =                
    ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Which are same as in SQL SERVER ; 1  ,  10 ,  Deposit
but it return no result /empty result .Strangely i believe it was working fine yesterday so no clue what is going on...

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you execute this command? How do you read the value of the output parameter? This is missing from your code above.

Comment: That part of the code is working fine as it does work for other similar procedure  where i don't have to use programName ...

Comment: My main concern is am i dealing correctly with string as ProgramName will be a string  if i use ID it works fine..

Comment: Of course that is a great problem. AddWithValue creates a parameter of the same type of the value that you pass. If your FeeType column is an Integer column and you pass a string parameter I would bet that something is not correctly retrieved. What is the type of the variable ProgramID, you say that its value is 'Deposit' right?

Comment: Strongly recommend `VARCHAR(nn)` instead of `VARCHAR` w/o a length; for example VARCHAR(10) if programID is INT

Comment: @Steve yes , ProgramID is a string Deposit/Fee Payment/Reset fee ec.

Comment: @Stan ok it worked perfectly i change to VARCHAR(50) and now i get results..

Comment: @Stan good catch. That's the problem. If you don't define a size then it is assumed to be 1 so the string passed is not 'Deposit' but only 'D' I suggest to post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VARCHAR()` without a specified length often defaults a length of 1 - the value you are passing is then silently truncated.

So

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTransactionFeeType_Pager]
     @PageIndex INT = 1
     ,@PageSize INT = 10
     ,@ProgramName VARCHAR(99) = ''
     ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS
...
```

does the trick by defining the length of @ProgramName